# How do you bind elements to SwiXML in JRuby?

Tags: jruby, swixml

I am trying to recreate SwiXML examples in JRuby. But the objects
created in JRuby never seem to be visible to SwiXML. Here is an example.

```
<frame size="200,200" title="Action Test">
  <menubar>
    <menu text="File">
      <menuitem action="quit" accelerator="meta X" />
    </menu>
  </menubar>
  <button action="quit" text="A Quit Button"
  ToolTipText="This is a quit button." />
</frame>
```

The Java code from the SwiXML example is as follows:

```
public class ActionTest {
  // Create an Action as a member variable
  public Action quit = new AbstractAction() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
      System.exit(0);
    }
  };
  public ActionTest() throws Exception {
    // set the Action's name
    quit.putValue(Action.NAME, "Quit");
    // build the GUI
    new SwingEngine(this).render("ActionTest.xml")
    .setVisible(true);
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new ActionTest();
  }
}
```

I have created some JRuby code to correspond to this, but it seems as if
the @quit member is never seen. Also tried referencing other named
elements (not in this example):

```
require 'java'
require 'java/swixml.jar'
require 'java/jdom.jar'

include_class 'javax.swing.AbstractAction'
include_class 'javax.swing.Action'
include_class 'javax.swing.JButton'

class MyAction < AbstractAction
  def actionPerformed(ae)
    exit # puts "Clicked"
  end
end

class Main < Object # Java::JavaLang::Object
  def initialize
    @quit = MyAction.new
    @quit.putValue(Action.NAME, "Quit")
    @f = java.io.File.new("sample.xml")
    @se = org.swixml.SwingEngine.new(self).render(@f).setVisible(true)
  end
end

Main.new
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been struggling with integrating JRuby and SwiXml this week. I've come to the conclusion that you can't have SwiXml automatically bind your variables/actions from the XML. (I think this is because in Java the variables already exist, whereas in JRuby they are created 'on-the-fly', so SwiXml isn't sure what to do. That's my conclusion, anyway, after hours of digging through source code. JRuby is fairly new to me, so someone more advanced might be able to tell me why this won't work.)

The solution is to simply bind them manually in the JRuby code. It's actually fairly easy, since this is Ruby.

```
include Java
java_import 'org.swixml.SwingEngine'

class HelloWorld

  def initialize
    @swix = SwingEngine.new(self)
    @swix.render("xml/helloworld.xml")
    btn = @swix.find("submit")
    btn.add_action_listener { |event| btn.text = 'Hi' }
  end

  def run
    @swix.getRootComponent.setVisible(true)
  end

end
```

See? Not too bad. In my case, "submit" is defined as the `<button>`'s ID attribute. So in my XML file I have `<button text="Click Here" id="submit" />` Think of the find() method like a findById() method (if you're familiar with DOM manipulation through JavaScript...).

Note that since the `add_action_listener` takes a block, instance variables (ivars) can be included in the block (in other words, it acts like you would expect a Java anonymous class/block to work). There's other ways to implement/add an action listener. See this page: https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/FAQs and scroll down to the section with a heading that says **How can I implement a Java Interface using a Ruby Class?**

Any element (as far as I know), can be retrieved by the SwingEngine class's `find()` method, as long as it's id is defined in the XML file.

A few minor things: `include_class` is now deprecated. You should use `java_import` instead. Also, your class that you're passing to SwingEngine does not need to inherit from `Object` or anything like that. JRuby is getting much better about making things more 'ruby-like' when integrating with Java.

Hope this helps. There's not much info out there about this stuff.

P.S. I found the info about 'manually binding' from this link: http://www.mail-archive.com/forum@carlsbadcubes.com/msg00062.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your answer here (My Ruby isn't good enough) - but I having a similar issue trying to use Jython here; this example partially works (it picks up the 'quit' action).

```
from org.swixml.jsr296 import SwingApplication
from org.jdesktop.application import Application
from javax.swing import JButton, JFrame

class MyFrame(JFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class Tester(SwingApplication):
    def __init__(self):
        self.frame=MyFrame()
        #self.frame=JFrame()

    def startup(self):
        print "Application Started"
        self.render(self.frame,"frame.xml").show()

    def shutdown(self):
        print "Application Shutdown"


    #def quit(self,evt):
    #   print "Over-ridden quit"

    def action1(self,evt):
        print "action1"

if __name__=='__main__':
     Application.launch(Tester,None)
```

I added in a second button in the XML like this:

```
<button action="action1" text="action1" ToolTipText="action1" />
```

But the additional 'action1' method is never seen by swixml it seems, I get the following output when I start (and then quit) the application:

```
Application Started
SwixML 2.5
11-Nov-2011 12:10:38 org.swixml.XAction <init>
WARNING: error on Action initialization [org.python.proxies.__main__$MyFrame$1.action1()]
Application Shutdown
```

The interesting thing is, if you uncomment the 'def quit(self,evt)' method ; this method IS seen by SXIWML; and the behaviour of the 'quit' button changes from shutting down the Application to printing out a message.

So it seems that something about the way SWIXML reflects to look for actions fails when the action is purely defined in Jython (Method signatures?): but over-riding an existing action method does work.

It would be really nice to see what is going on here - I might log a new StackOverFlow question on this example and reference this one.

It would be great to be able to quickly throw together simple SWING apps using JRuby / Jython (etc) using SWIXMl; but a working template of how to do this is needed I think.

The other strange thing that I cannot explain ; if the line 'self.frame=MyFrame()' is changed to instantiate a standard JFrame: 'self.frame.JFrame()' - this results in classloader errors:

```
SwixML 2.5
11-Nov-2011 12:19:14 org.swixml.XAction <init>
WARNING: error on Action initialization [null ClassLoader]
11-Nov-2011 12:19:14 org.swixml.XAction <init>
WARNING: error on Action initialization [null ClassLoader]
11-Nov-2011 12:19:14 org.swixml.XAction <init>
WARNING: error on Action initialization [null ClassLoader]
```

Comment: I'm not convinced by my own example here: the example works - but not for the reasons I thought it does - I'm unable to define other actions other than 'quit' : which is already built in (I think) to the 'SwingApplication' Object. If I get a solution I'll re-post.

Comment: I have since edited my answer after posting the comment above - still not working but have added extra notes.